# App Store Binary Rejected - The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have recently uploaded a new application to iTunes Connect for the approval process. Its version is 1.0. Today the binary was rejected and the following was mentioned in the resolution center.

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name,
“￼Secured” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Secured￼ brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page.

We have generated the application using the proper profiles. Any idea as to when this issue is raised by Apple? We could not get any proper information about the reason and the way to resolve it. Does this have anything to do with the application name being similar to some other application named as "Secured" and out app name being Secured?

Comment: It will be very helpful if someone from the community who faced such issue can let us know.

Comment: I am having the same issue today. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: I too am having the same issue today. Any solution? Note that to me, 'If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.' is not a solution.

Comment: For us, we had to mention that we already own the registered trademark of the name of the application and the logo. We responded to this information in the Resolution Center. After 2 days, we found that they had approved the application. We did not even have to re-submit any new build. I think that we need to provide the information that the name that we are using is actually owned by the rightful owner, the one that is submitting the application.

Comment: You said: 'We responded to this information in the Resolution Center'. Do you mean where it says there 'reply'?

Comment: @RJB Yes. You put in the information in the textbox and click on the reply button. They will send the information to the Apple Review Team who is reviewing the application (I suppose).

Comment: @Soumya. I had the same problem today with my first app. I did the app for a small company, and they rejected it with the message like you got. I don't understand what I am supposed to do to get it accepted? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Ok. i never knew about that.

Comment: We're having the same issue. We host apps on our account for multiple clients who all sign up to use our service with a branded white label style app. We will need to set up and maintain over 50 separate accounts if we follow this. This hasn't been an issue until this month and we have been submitting apps and updates monthly for several years this way.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern related to the App Store, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: I was added financial institute name list in metadata since 2 years, Now latest version rejected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You typically get this kind of rejection when you submit an app that has some known brand in the name of the app, icon, inside the app or in the metadata. For example, if your company is "Milkshakes Ltd." and you use "Nike" brand in the name of your app "Milkshakes - *Nike* Edition".

This typically happens when a company asks you - the developer - to create and app for them and you are trying to release the app under your developer account. But the app needs to be released under the company developer account (the company needs to enroll Apple Developer Program if it has not yet done so). That is why Apple advises the following:

> If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Releasing apps under a different account is against Apple Developer Program License Agreement:

> For the sake of clarity, You may authorize contractors to develop Applications on Your behalf, but any such Applications must be owned by You, submitted under Your own developer account, and distributed as Applications only as expressly permitted herein. You are responsible to Apple for Your contractors’ activities under Your account (e.g., adding them to Your team to perform development work for You) and their compliance with this Agreement. Any actions undertaken by Your contractors arising out of this Agreement shall be deemed to have been taken by You, and You (in addition to Your contractors) shall be responsible to Apple for all such actions.

However, based on your description, it does not look this is your case. I don't know about any well known "Secured" or "Safe" brands. You did not write your company name, there might be a conflict too. I would try to clarify the issue with Apple Review Team by responding to the issue in Resolution Center. They might point you to the brand you are in conflict with. Or it might have been rejected by a mistake.

Comment: I am getting same issue and I cant say client to add me in their  Apple Developer account. Please tell me another solution.

Comment: Either the client adds you into their Developer account or you send them your source code or compiled archive and they submit it to the App Store themselves.

Comment: Thank you .but my client don't have Apple Developer Account. We always submit application from our Developer Account.

Comment: So either convince your client to enroll to Apple Developer Program or discuss the issue with Apple Review Team by responding to the issue in Resolution Center.

Comment: Running into this issue as well the thing is we build apps for clients but we retain all rights to the application, they don't own any part of it...do you know if this is a recent change to the Apple Developer Program Agreement, or do you know where I can find a history of the agreements and see what has changed over time? Haven't had any luck finding past agreements.

Comment: How can Apple know about the brands? I mean, how can they know whether you own the brand "Secured" or not?

Comment: Let's say As a developer I want to add the application under my apple developer account and not under my client's developer account and I ask my client to add my account as developer under their account. Is it possible.? In the end, I want to add this app under my developer account.

Comment: I am developing Government application and I have attached agreement of both parties  during app submission through my developer account but app is rejected twice. One way  I found is submitting app through client account, but this might not possible to make developer account of the every client, So please give me alternate solution for this as I can provide any document to the apple store.

Answer (score 20):

I found a comment in Apple Developer forum, and it works for me.

> rajveer123
>   Mar 14, 2017 10:46 AM
>   (in response to nikhileshrayapureddy)
>
> Hi,
>   I might be able to help on this. I just got my app approved and had
>   the same reason.   You need to make sure, that if your app is called
>   XYZ and you are the owner 123, that 123 owns all copyright for the app
>   and it's content within. If the content is third-party make sure you
>   comment this in comments box. It's quite reasonable, as I might upload
>   an app called Windows for iOS and do not even own the copyright for
>   this brand. Also, make sure you write the correct name etc. in the
>   copyright box, who owns the brand. It's not the app name, but the
>   publisher or if you develop for someone, it's his company/client name.
>   I don't think it's that complictaed with Apple, you just need to be
>   straight forward.   I hope this helps someone!

Link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73820

From the comment, I did as below:

- In "Prepare for submission", scroll to Copyright area, copy your
     team name and paste it as Copyright of this application.

  - Resubmit your application.

In my case, it took 2 days to get my application approved for sale in Apple store. Have your patience.

[image]

UPDATED: Now, apple allows us upload a certificate file to show their authentication of this app then we can use the our owner app name. 
[image]

Comment: I wonder why they can't be a bit more direct like, "The copyright of your application says XYZ and not 'Linh Nguyen'.".

Comment: @Josejulio: "Linh Nguyen" is only  a member's name of an Apple Developer Account, not the name of Apple Developer Account. My post and  my image is help you to clear the comment.

Comment: I know, I used it as an example :).

Comment: @ahmad: is your account is individual account.

Comment: @biolinh it's a corporate account for a customer of ours.

Comment: @biolinh what if it is an individual account? I am having trouble uploading the app through my clients individual account.

Comment: @abhi1992: for individual account, if you are developer/ceo/founder for this app and you can prove for Apple by website/paper or etc. Apple can accept that.

Answer (score 5):

We ran into the same issue. Basically it's a trademark issue. I'm not arguing if it's right or wrong. But the solution:

1. Either you have to list in the developer account of your customer.
2. Or legally acquire the trademark and brand name of your customer (may be limited for the purpose of AppStore/PlayStore/Digital Marketing)

I know point 2 sounds a bit off. I agree it is.

Let's take an example:

*Developer*: FooBar Software
*App*: No1 Pharma

In AppStore listing, the seller of the app is the developer. So from the user point of view, if you look at the listing on AppStore, it would say the app "No1 Pharma" is being sold by "FooBar Software". This doesn't sound right.

Another case:

The publishing rights of Harry Potter Books (acc. to wiki) is owned by Bloomsbury Publishing (UK) and Scholastic (US)

*Developer*: Bloomsbury Publishing
*App*: Harry Potter

This will sound right, in spite of the fact that the seller name and app name did not match. The listing would read "Bloomsbury Publishing" is the seller of the app "Harry Potter". This sounds right. So Bloomsbury can publish all the trademarks/brands it owns as different apps in it's developer account.

Perhaps AppStore might choose to differentiate the developers from sellers. Because developers are not sellers. That's the reality.

Let's say IBM develops the "Harry Potter" app for "Bloomsbury", then the listing should read:

*Developer*: IBM
*Seller*: Bloomsbury
*App*: Harry Potter

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. They accepted it after I changed the **individual membership account to a company/Organisation membership** & uploaded it again. If your product is a brand which is registered, it should be a company account which reflects the brand name of your product

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and it was resolved, Now when you develop an app on apple store it would be one of these two options:

- You are developing it on behalf of another person or organization and either your account is an individual or organization you must provide apple with the apple account for the client because this client is the real owner for the app.
- The second option is that you develop this app for your self and you are the owner for it, in this case, if you are an individual you must inform apple that you own this as individual (this is my case) and they will resolve it to you, you can reach the support team by creating a case on the resolution center and resubmit your app again. I believe similar steps should be made for organization account.

But an important thing to take it into account, that you are the real owner of this app and you are not using other one brand.

Hope this helps