# PLA 1.2 The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name, “Lumique,” in the app or its metadata, as required

Tags: ios

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Lumique brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Comment: How i can solve this isssues

Comment: As Apple explained; if your app was developed for Lumique then they must publish the app under their own company membership. If you are not affiliated with Lumique then you cannot publish your app in its current form

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a question about the App store, and as such isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Its about Apple App store policies, not programming.

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: @DuncanC it's a problem that can occur to every developer publishing his app in iTunes Connect. And questions about iTunesConnect are over the SO ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. So this is the right place.

Comment: Developers don't publish apps, businesses do. This is a business question, not a developer question, @qua

Comment: @Vikas Bro what solution you ended with ...

Comment: i got stuck in this still now

Comment: @VikasKumar did you find any solution?I am facing same problem.

Comment: You have to submit build from client or company Developer account

Comment: Please visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511575) to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again i got this rejection again, Let me explain how i had fixed this issue.

> I scheduled a call with review team and explain about my product
>   authority and agreement i.e There is not copyright issue with that. I
>   have also send a soft copy of agreement about my app after 2 days my
>   app had been lived on appstore.