# Binary Rejected in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, apple-developer

PLA 1.2

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “Secure￼” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Secure brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page.

Whats the problem.

Comment: did you try to publish from client account? or any other account? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about AppStore and not about programming.