# iOS app issue - How to resolve?

Tags: ios, metadata, status, phonegap

I'm trying to upload an `iOS` app which is developed in Phone gap, But app got rejected by saying this issue. I found same problem for few users ,[previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap?rq=1) .But nothing worked for me

> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect
>   the name “my app name” in the app or its metadata, as required by section
>   1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

> Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that
>   reflects the app brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf
>   of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development
>   team of their Apple Developer account.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: In which account have you created the bundle identifier for the app? Are you using the same iTunes Connect account for uploading?

Comment: Please [search on your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+The+seller+and+company+names+associated+with+your+app+do+not+reflect+the+name) before posting.

Comment: I was using client account for upload , i had used same account for iTunes connect Uploaing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all reply .My app got approved , I have send a mail to apple review team they approved app .I think that was the Simple solution .

Answer (score 2):

Use client iTunes account for upload app, If client are not able to provide their login credential ask him to send invitation on your id so you can upload app from your account for send invitation login client iTunes account and go Users and Roles section and send invitation

Comment: Actually I am using client account for app uploading,

Answer (score 1):

> If you enroll as an individual, the company name is the same as your
>   legal name. In the store, the “company name” is used prominently for
>   navigation and to group your apps. Your legal entity name appears as
>   the “seller” of your apps. For example, “Apple” is the company name
>   and “Apple, Inc” is the seller name. When users tap your company name,
>   they see all of the apps you have on the store.