# PLA 1.2 The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “Company Name”

Tags: xcode8

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “Company Name” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App Store Binary Rejected - The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap)

Comment: okay thanks. I got the solution, In my app i was using the company logo originally which is not belongs to me , in that case we need to upload the binary using company which logo owns. this solution given by apple customer care.

Comment: Glad it helped. I guess ours was solved by changing "copyright" field. (not sure, it's been 7 days app is "in review")