# Xamarin iOS app got rejected in AppStoreConnect by saying that "Seller and Company name is not reflect the App name"

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect

I upload Xamarin iOS app on AppStoreConnect to get approval from apple to upload it on the app store. But they reject it by saying that **Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the NONCO name. If you have developed this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account. If your client does not yet have an Apple Developer account, they can enroll in the Apple Developer Program through the Apple Developer website**.

To resolve this issue I upload a certificate certified by Client itself which certify that The Nonco (app name) is an initiative of PROSINNO PRIVATE LIMITED (Client's organization name). I Use client's organization apple developer account to upload it on appStoreConnect but still they reject the app.

I upload app several times but it got rejected every time.Now i got struck and don't understand what to do to resolve this issue.[Refrence image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcd4G.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap

Comment: Add your team in the client apple developer account - under Membership tag https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: @Prasanth I am uploading app through client's company developer account, not through mine. I think your answer is correct in case if I upload App through my apple account.

Comment: You need an organisational membership for the company "Nonco".

Comment: @Paulw11 NONCO is the name of the app and Company name is PROSINNO PRIVATE LIMITED. Is there anything which is missing?

Comment: Apple wants the seller name to be NONCO. You will need to work it out with them.

Comment: @Paulw11 You mean I have to change organisation name **PROSINNO PRIVATE LIMITED** to **NONCO**  in apple account? please see image for reference.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The development program membership needs to match the company branding in the app